# Word VBA TrackRevisions with comment pane

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error, comments, change-tracking

I understand there have been issues since Microsoft changed the way comments are handled (this is MS Word). I have a proofreading macro that includes the line "If ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False" at the very start.

I get the following error message: *Run-time error 4605.* *The TrackRevisions method or property is not available because comment card is selected in pane.*

It looks like the error appears if the comment is actually open, i.e. selected.

Is there a way to 'de-select' the comment without moving the cursor back into the document?

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're having, can you give us a sample or some example screenshots to see what's going on?

Comment: @OscarSun The problem is easy to reproduce: Just show the comments pane and start to edit a comment (so that the cursor is within the text field)

Comment: @oscarsun - as funthomas says, just have the cursor in the comment's text field, then run a macro mentioning ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just can't reproduce the problem you met by showing the comments pane so I commented on this. All you said I had tried.